# using a datatemplate to dynamically load radpanes and property grids

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, datatemplate

I'm using some telerik components and am trying to do the following:
I have a `TabCollection` which is a observable collection of `ConfigurationTab` I want to create a radPane for every ConfigurationTab in this collection (this i have managed sort of) then i want the current tab to display a `RadPropertyGrid` to which I will bind a (custom) collection of properties.

The code is as follows:
(XAML)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabCollectionTemplate">
        <telerik:RadPane CanUserClose="False" Header="{Binding DisplayName}">
            <telerik:RadPropertyGrid Margin="0,4,0,4"
                                     assistant:PropertyGridAssistant.AllowDescription="True"
                                     assistant:PropertyGridAssistant.AllowReset="True"
                                     valid:ValidationAssistant.IsEnabled="True"
                                     valid:ValidationAssistant.IsValid="{Binding IsTaskValid,
                                                                                 Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                     BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
                                     DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                     EnableEditorCaching="False"
                                     Item="{Binding Path=TabPropertyCollection,
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                     SearchBoxVisibility="Collapsed"
                                     SortAndGroupButtonsVisibility="Visible" />
        </telerik:RadPane>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <telerik:RadDocking Name="ConfigurationDocking">
        <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedRight">
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabCollectionTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}" />
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
    </telerik:RadDocking>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public class ConfigurationTab : ObservableObject
{
    private string mDisplayName = string.Empty;
    private Property.Management.Properties mProperties = new Property.Management.Properties();

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return mDisplayName;
        }
        set
        {
            mDisplayName = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.DisplayName);
        }
    }

    public Property.Management.Properties TabProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return mProperties;
        }
        set
        {
            mProperties = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.TabProperties);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.TabPropertyCollection);
        }
    }

    public PropertiesToPropertyGridAdapter<DescriptorOfProperty> TabPropertyCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return new PropertiesToPropertyGridAdapter<DescriptorOfProperty>(mProperties);
        }
    }
```

The thing i get using the current code looks as follows, the headers of the tabs are filled in correctly with the display name but the part where the content of the pane only ever displays: "IOLAN.ModuleConfigurationTester.ConfigurationTab" which is the problem:
[image]

Also when I click on the 2nd tab I get a null reference exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

An interesting thing to add, if i change my data template to a simple textbox It changes nothing, the only thing i see in the radpane = "IOLAN.ModuleConfigurationTester.ConfigurationTab" and i still get a null reference trying to open the other tab:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabCollectionTemplate">
    <telerik:RadPane CanUserClose="False" Header="{Binding DisplayName}">
        <TextBox Text="Hallo" />
    </telerik:RadPane>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a while i figured out what I had to do, i simply had to use a TablControl and set the content template, doing it like this solved all the problems:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate">
        <telerik:RadPropertyGrid Name="PropertyGrid"
                                 Margin="0,4,20,4"
                                 assistant:PropertyGridAssistant.AllowDescription="True"
                                 assistant:PropertyGridAssistant.AllowReset="True"
                                 BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
                                 IsGrouped="True"
                                 Item="{Binding Path=TabPropertyCollection,
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 SearchBoxVisibility="Collapsed" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <telerik:RadDocking>
        <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
            <DockPanel>
                <telerik:RadTabControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate}"
                                       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}"
                                       SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,
                                                              Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
    </telerik:RadDocking>
</Grid>
```